# Recover data from encrypted btrieve file

Tags: data-recovery, encryption, btrieve

i've a simple question, but huge issue for me.

i have need to recover the data which is in a encrypted btrieve file, for migration purpose, but i can't access to the record structure.

Someone knowns a technique for that? or opensource program?

Thanks for any help or direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

By "encrypted," do you mean it has an owner name or do you mean that when you open it in a text editor, it looks strange?

Btrieve data files require the Btrieve / Pervasive PSQL engine in order to be read.  Once you have the engine, you can open it and read it.  You'll still need to know the record layout (or guess) in order to extract meaningful data from it.  Btrieve files do not store field metadata so any Btrieve tool will only see the record as a collection of bytes.

If you know the record structure, you can create a table definition using DDF Builder or the Pervasive Control Center, and then access the table using ODBC (or JDBC, ADO.NET, PDAC, ActiveX, or OLEDB) and extract the data using your favorite tool.

Comment: thanks.. the files has an owner name, and i don't known. but if i can read the data maybe i guess the structure.

Comment: Some owner name levels allow for read only access.  Have you tried using Function Executor to open the file?